# Sending double value from one class to another in C#

Tags: c#, class, double, return-value, kinect

I wonder how I can send a double value from one class to another. I'm working with a Kinect and when the double "distance" is calculated in my public class main while I have my hand closed I wish to send that information to my other public class Monitor. Shown examples would be highly appreciated as I'm beginner in C# programming.

```
private void DrawHand(HandState handState, Point handPosition, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        switch (handState)
        {
            case HandState.Closed:
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handClosedBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
                // Distance calculation
                foreach (var body in bodies)
                {
                    // Get the positions
                    pRH = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                    pLH = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]; // pLH gets to be "home" position in the meanwhile
                    //Some maths
                    double sqDistance = Math.Pow(pRH.Position.X - pLH.Position.X, 2) +
                        Math.Pow(pRH.Position.Y - pLH.Position.Y, 2) +
                        Math.Pow(pRH.Position.Z - pLH.Position.Z, 2);


                    // This is the information I want to send to public class Monitor
                    double distance = Math.Sqrt(sqDistance);

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please write your question more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send your distance variable to monitor class in many ways

> **1. Constructor**
>
> **2. Properties**
>
> **3. Method**

```
 private void DrawHand(HandState handState, Point handPosition, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        switch (handState)
        {
            case HandState.Closed:
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handClosedBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
                // Distance calculation
                foreach (var body in bodies)
                {
                    // Get the positions
                    pRH = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                    pLH = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]; // pLH gets to be "home" position in the meanwhile
                    //Some maths
                    double sqDistance = Math.Pow(pRH.Position.X - pLH.Position.X, 2) +
                        Math.Pow(pRH.Position.Y - pLH.Position.Y, 2) +
                        Math.Pow(pRH.Position.Z - pLH.Position.Z, 2);


                    // This is the information I want to send to public class Monitor
                    double distance = Math.Sqrt(sqDistance);
                    // Create object of Monitor class and pass the distance 
                    Moniotr obj = new Monitor(distance);
                   // using Method 
                    Moniotr obj = new Monitor();
                    obj.setDistance(distance);
                  // using public property
                  Moniotr obj = new Monitor();
                  obj.Distance = distance;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is Sample Monitor Class With Constructor approach

```
public class Monitor 
{
   public Monitor(double distance)
   {
   }
}
```

Here is Sample Monitor Class With Method approach

```
public class Monitor 
    {
       public void setDistance(double distance)
       {

       }
    }
```

Here is Sample Monitor class with Property approach

```
public class Monitor 
{
  private double _distance;
  public Distance
  {
    get{return _distance;}
    set{_distance=value;}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what your trying to achieve, however you can return values by

```
return value;
```

This is received by the calling class by

```
double temp = method();
```

If you are trying to send the value double to a class then you should use a parameter.

For example :-

```
Monitor monitor1 = new Monitor(distance);
```

or by

```
Monitor monitor1 = new Monitor();
monitor1.setDistance(distance);
```

Comment: Unless Monitor is a static class, in which case it should be Monitor.setDistance(distance).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood your question is this what you want

```
 public class Monitor
        {      
public  Monitor(double distance)//Constructor with double as parameter 
            {

            }
        }
```

When you instantiate this class

```
Monitor mo=new Monitor(distance);
```